# Unable to modify children in parsed html

Tags: reactjs, html-react-parser

I want to render a large chunk of html by replacing specific tags such as `<p>` and `<a>` with React components(i.e. `<StyledParagraph>` and `<StyledLink>`)

I've tested many libraries including html-react-parser. Unlike many others, html-react-parser has an example that addresses my need. But, I cannot get the example to work. (Using React 16.5.3)

```
const test = () =>
  <>
    {parse(
      `
      <p id="main">
        <span class="prettify">
          keep me and make me pretty!
        </span>
      </p>
    `,
      {
        replace: ({ attribs, children }) => {
          if (!attribs) return;

          if (attribs.id === 'main') {
            return (
              <h1 style={{ fontSize: 42 }}>
                {domToReact(children)}
              </h1>
            );
          } else if (attribs.class === 'prettify') {
            return (
              <span style={{ color: 'hotpink' }}>
                {domToReact(children)}
              </span>
            );
          }
        }
      }
    )}
  </>
```

I did not pass `parserOptions` to the `domToReact` function, because I haven't found the documentation for those options yet.

Expected results:

```
<h1 style="font-size:42px">
  <span style="color:hotpink">keep me and make me pretty!</span>
</h1>
```

So far, I cannot modify the nested nodes (in this case `<span>`).

Actual results:

```
<h1 style="font-size: 42px;">
    <span class="prettify">keep me and make me pretty!</span>
  </h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a `replace` function to `domToReact` as part of its `options` param. From the source:

```
/**
 * Converts DOM nodes to React elements.
 *
 * @param  {Array}    nodes             - The DOM nodes.
 * @param  {Object}   [options]         - The additional options.
 * @param  {Function} [options.replace] - The replace method.
 * @return {ReactElement|Array}
 */
```

In the case of this example that would mean...

```
function replaceHtmlWithReact({ attribs, children }) {
  if (!attribs) return;

  if (attribs.id === 'main') {
    return (
      <h1 style={{ fontSize: 42 }}>
        {domToReact(children, { replace: replaceHtmlWithReact })}
      </h1>
    );
  } else if (attribs.class === 'prettify') {
    return (
      <span style={{ color: 'hotpink' }}>
        {domToReact(children, { replace: replaceHtmlWithReact })}
      </span>
    );
  }
}

const test = () => 
<>
  {parse(
    `
      <p id="main">
        <span class="prettify">
          keep me and make me pretty!
        </span>
      </p>
    `,{ replace: replaceHtmlWithReact }
  )}
</>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this working without `domToReact` option.  I am passing an HTML string from a JSON object fetched from Wordpress to `react-syntax-highlighter`.  I haven't examined the `html-react-parser` source code yet to see what the difference is between using the two, but replacing an HTML tag with JSX appears to work with `domNode.attribs` just fine.

This component takes that JSON object (which is comprised of Wordpress posts), maps each post to a separate parsed section, and then replaces each `pre` tag of each parsed section that meets a certain criteria (in this case, `class=wp-block-code` or `class=CodeMirror`) with a JSX `SyntaxHighlighter` tag, while retaining the text of the codeblock (`domNode.children[0].data`).

Notes: While analyzing the JSON object, I saw that none of these `domNode.children` arrays had more than one position, so position `[0]` was all that was required in my case - obviously, your needs may vary.

None of the commands from `html-react-parser` or JSON objects retrieved from Wordpress are destructured, so you can see the clear delineation of the API/commands.

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
import SyntaxHighlighter from 'react-syntax-highlighter';
import { gruvboxDark } from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs';

export const Blog = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>This is an example of a blog component</h1>
      <div>
        {props.posts.map((post, index) => (
          <div key={post.id}>
            <h3>{post.id}</h3>
            <div>{parse(post.title.rendered)}</div>
            <div>{parse(post.excerpt.rendered)}</div>
            <div>
              {parse(post.content.rendered, {
                replace: (domNode) => {
                  if (
                    (domNode.attribs && domNode.attribs.class === 'CodeMirror') ||
                    (domNode.attribs && domNode.attribs.class === 'wp-block-code')
                  ) {
                    return (
                      <SyntaxHighlighter
                        language="bash"
                        showLineNumbers={true}
                        style={gruvboxDark}
                        wrapLongLines={true}
                      >
                        {domNode.children[0].data}
                      </SyntaxHighlighter>
                    );
                  }
                },
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```